# Can an ASMX web service return a blank XML doc under certain conditions?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

Pseudocode Example:

```
string data = GetDataFromDB();

if(data != null)
    return XMLDocument;
else 
    break;
```

The reason I want to do this is to reduce throughput if there is no data in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could either return null, or if you don't like that, then return a new object.
Your actual code would be something like this:

```
if(data != null)
  return new XMLDocument();
else break;
```

Consider that in SOAP, a `null` is serialized into an XML fragment which has a non 0 length

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I have a webservice within a WebApp that returns an empty response if the service has done as requested and they was no data to return.  I did however, ensure the the serivce returns a "200 - OK" status with data and a "204 - No content" status with no data.

Use the [HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) enum, so your code has `HttpStatusCode.OK` or `HttpStatusCode.NoContent` and not 200 or 204.  This allows later coders to see intent at a glance and not have to know that 204 means No Content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But that does not mean you should. If the consumers of your service expects a return value in return, it will create a strange bug for them to not receive anything. It clearly goes against the [principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

On the other hand, if you are the one making the code consuming the web service, feel free to do as you wish!

Edit:

if you want to reduce bandwidth usage, you may consider not using the SOAP xml serializer and perhaps instead using SOAP binary serializer (or/and you could enable content compression for your service). If you want a cross platform web service that's less verbose than SOAP (and less bandwidth consuming), you could also use plain old xml/json. In this case, WCF Web API is a very good platform.